Ubuntu 24, corrupted graphics for kernel version > 6.8.0-36
I'm using Ubuntu 24.04 with a Dell XPS 17. There's no physical GPU so I'm using integrated graphics.
For some reason, if I boot up my laptop with any kernel version later than 6.8.0-36, my graphics are horribly corrupted, including the latest version 6.8.0-45.
Is there anything I can do here?

Can you please share more details aDout the integrated graphics?

I never found a working fix for Ubuntu 24.04 but upgrading my laptop to 24.10 and kernel 6.11 seems to have fixed everything.
Even before, the built-in audio didn't work on 24.04 and now it does on 24.10. Go figure that randomly upgrading eventually fixes things.
